# Global zustand useEffect update

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, zustand

I have created a zustand store that looks something like:

```
import { create } from "zustand";
import myDataStore from "./myDataStore";

type State = {
    combinedData: any;
    combineData: () => void;
};

const myCombinedData = create<State>((set) => ({
    combinedData: [],
    combineData: () =>
        set(() => {
            const myData = myDataStore.getState().data;

            const newCombinedData = myData.df.map((item, index) => {
                return { ...item, ...myData.df_other[index] };
            });
            return { combinedData: newCombinedData };
        }),
}));

export default myCombinedData;
```

So basically I have another zustand store that stores some data (`myDataStore`), which I then use to create some other data.

On the component side I call it via:

```
const myData = myDataStore((state) => state.data);
const { combinedData, combineData } = myCombinedData();

useEffect(() => {
    combineData();
}, [myData]);
```

So since I need the `myData` on this component, I call it, and then everything works if I use the `useEffect`. However, my issue is, that I use this `combinedData` on multiple components, and it just doesn't seem right to use a `useEffect` on every component. So isn't there a way to just update the `combinedData` in one place, every time `myData` changes?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but your issue is that computed/derived properties are not baked into Zustand. That is what you are trying to do. So, you can import zustand-derived (a third party import I think from the same author of zustand, https://github.com/dai-shi/derive-zustand), or you can try something like this -- it uses a "getter" in the object method and can simulate a computed properties.

Change this:

```
    combineData: () =>
        set(() => {
            const myData = myDataStore.getState().data;

            const newCombinedData = myData.df.map((item, index) => {
                return { ...item, ...myData.df_other[index] };
            });
            return { combinedData: newCombinedData };
        }),
```

To something like:

```
 computed: {
      get combineData(){
        set(() => {
            const myData = myDataStore.getState().data;

            const newCombinedData = myData.df.map((item, index) => {
                return { ...item, ...myData.df_other[index] };
            });
            return { combinedData: newCombinedData };
        })
      },
    },
```

then use it like so:

```
  /* Stores */
  const combineData= useMyCombinedData (state => state.computed.combineData);
```

also, it is best practice to use the "hook" naming convention as you are using hooks. In fact, I'd be inclined to first rename your stores, see if the renaming works... if not, try my update.... update your stores names with "useYourStoreName".

OR: instead of using multiple stores, just use one store.